# Is there a way to get or define typeid of a template?

Tags: c++, templates, typeinfo

I have a template class which is dependent on multiple template class, like following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <typename _T> 
struct Foo {
    _T mem;
};

template <typename _T> 
struct Bar {
    _T mem;
};

template <template <typename> typename ... _Dependencies>
struct Target {
    static std::vector<std::string> getSignature() {
        std::vector<std::string> vec{typeid(_Dependencies<int>).name()...};
        return vec;
    };
}; 

int main () {
    for (auto& item : Target<Foo, Bar>::getSignature()) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }; 
    return 0;
}
```

please notice this line:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec{typeid(_Dependencies<int>).name()...};
```

Here I have to give the template a specific type (e.g. `int`,`std::string` or sth else) to make the compile pass. However, what i want to get is not the instantiation template type, it is about the type of template class self, in order to distinguish between them.

Is it possible? or I have to use some instantiation type to achieve my aim ?

Comment: Class template is not a type. A specialization of that template is a type. You can't write `typeid(Foo)` for the same reason you can't, say, declare a variable of type `Foo`, as in `Foo x;`

Comment: Think about it this way: A template doesn't even exist until you instantiate it with some type.

Comment: I know it is the fact. Howerver, if i use int, I get "3FooIiE, 3BarIiE" , and if i use std::string, I get "3FooINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE, 3BarINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE". I can see the "3FooI[PLACEHOLDER]E" pattern in both case, and that's what i want to get. I think if there is some key word  `templateid` , it would be perfect.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_T`, `_Dependencies`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are not types.  Only types have typeids.

```
template<template<class...>class>struct template_tag{};
```

this is a template.

```
template_tag<_Dependencies>
```

this is a type.

Take the typeid of `template_tag<your template>`.

## Aside:

Note that a program where you name a type `_Dependencies` is ill formed no diagnostic required.  Please stop mimicing std headers.  They can name types things you are not allowed to.

Never name anything a name starting with a `_` followed by a capital letter.  Never name anything something containing two `__`s.  Both are reserved by the standard only to be used by compilers and std oibrary implementors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just want to know, is there a specification or standard show that style is reserved / not permitted and should only be used in STL, unless writing extensions for it ?   and is there any compiler special treatment for such coding style?  I know  there are __ leading reserved macros in compiler, but just template parameter will also result in sth unusual ?

Comment: Besides,  `template<template<class...>class>struct template_tag{}` is different with `template<template<class>class...>struct template_tag{}` one is a template with varadic template class as dependence, the other is a varadic template with template as dependence.

Comment: Try it before you complain.  The C++ standard describes the reserved names.  The std library is part of the languange implementation; it can do anything, so long as the compiler generates the required behaviour when you `#include` it.  If you want to know more onnthe subject press [ask question].

Comment: I am not complaining, just want to know the where is the standard : ) thanks again for your help. I found it in the 2017 N4713.  section 5.10.3.1 & 5.10.3.2  [links_here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf). for anyone else who may also need it.

Comment: Also your answer is very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your answer again! Now I know there are two ways to get template related type which is recognizable with `typeid`: 1. to instantiate it with its dependent type/types. 2. create a template class (in your example `template_tag`) which accept template as a parameter. the way you suggest is much more elegant and well suit my aim!